# Postgres and TypeORM WHERE clause filters JOIN table

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

Hi guys I'm trying to use TypeORM with postgres to query some users from database.

I have two models: **Users** and **Grades**, its one to many relationship, User can have many grades

**User model:**

```
import {
    Entity,
    Column,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
    ManyToOne,
    OneToMany,
    Index,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Grade } from './grade.entity';

@Entity('users')
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'id', type: 'integer' })
    id: number;

    @Index()
    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    surname: string;


    @OneToMany(() => Grade, (grade) => grade.user, {
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        cascade: true,
    })
    grades: Grades[];


}
```

**Grade model.**

```
import {
    Entity,
    Column,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
    ManyToOne,
} from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './User.entity';

@Entity('grades')
export class Grade {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'id', type: 'integer' })
    id: number;

    @Column()
    value: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, (asset) => user.grades)
    user: User;
}
```

I have the following query:

```
this.createQueryBuilder('users')
            .innerJoinAndSelect('users.grades', 'grade')
            .where('grade.value IN (:5)', { ips })
            .getMany();
```

The problem is that when query is run, it also filters grades inside of user

So I multiple Users and grades like this:

```
Users(name: 'John', surname: 'Doe')(name: 'Stiv', surname: 'Jovic ') and grades -> ( value: 1 ), ( value:2 ), ( value: 3 ), ( value:4 ), ( value:5), ( value:6), ( value:2)
```

I would like to get all users with grade 5, so I get it like this:

```
User(name: 'John) => grades (value: 1),(value: 2),(value: 5)
```

But know I get Users with grade 5, but it also filters the join table, so I get data like this:

```
User(name: 'John') => grades (value:5)
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: I added that tag by mistake, thank you .. fix it now

Comment: 9.4 is no longer supported either

Comment: Can you please add your entities? And I'm not sure I understand what exactly are you trying to do. You want to select the users that at least one of their grades have the value of 5?

Comment: @noamsteiner Hi, I have added models, the problems that Im having is that my where clause also filters grades, but I would like only to filter users by grade, and keep all grades

Comment: To make sure, you want to select all grades and join users only for grades  with the value of 5? Also I'm a bit confused, the type of `OneToMany` in `User` class is `Attribute` instead of `Grade`. In Grade class you have `(asset) => user.grades`, does this even compile?

Comment: @noamsteiner Yes thats right, that is what I would like to achieve... Yes I made a mistake I have different models, but logic is the same (updated it now)

Answer (score 2):

First of all it is important to understand the join types, you used `INNER JOIN` which will always return only the intersection of users and grades.

[image]

To select all grades and join users only for grades with the value of 5, you should use `RIGHT JOIN`, so that table 1 is `users` and table 2 is `grades` and the intersection will be the users with grade 5 and above.

[image]

#### BUT

due to [this comment](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/887#issuecomment-329513821) in typeorm's github, it is not possible to implement `RIGHT JOIN` while working with an ORM.

Than what can you do?

1. select all grades and `LEFT JOIN` users with the grade value condition:

Tadble 1 is `grades` and table 2 is `users`.

[image]

```
this.createQueryBuilder('grades')
            .leftJoinAndSelect('grades.user', 'user', 'grades.value IN (:5)')
            .getMany();
```

2. you cane write a raw query such as:

```
this.gardesRepository.query(`
    SELECT * FROM grades
    RIGHT JOIN users ON grades.user_id = users.id AND grades.value IN (:5);
`)
```